# Set background image using jQuery.each() and :contains()

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to using `jQuery.each()` and was wondering why this wasn't working ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaiyanToaster/8b6m5jf1/)):

```
$('span.cleanup').on('click', function() {
    $('table tr td p span:contains("0")').each(function (i) {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('assets/clean.png')");
    });
});
```

Note: `$('table tr td p span:contains("0")').css("background-image", "url('assets/masteries/gray_mastery0.png')");` doesn't seem to work either.

Anyone able to explain how `.each()` works when setting something for multiple matching objects?

Comment: can you show your table structure? or create a fiddle for it .

Comment: @AmitKumar - I literately just added a snippet of the table :D

Comment: check your updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/8b6m5jf1/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but your fiddle was setup incorrectly. Also even if the click event had fired, you wouldn't have noticed the background image because the top left corner is white.

This works perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/8b6m5jf1/7/

```
$('span.cleanup').on('click', function() {

    $('table tr td p span:contains("0")').css("background-image", "url(http://critterbabies.com/wp-content/gallery/kittens/cute-kitten-playing.jpg)");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not because you use wrong selector, it's just because your image is far bigger then the span's width/height..

```
imageUrl = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png'
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('span.cleanup').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr td p span:contains("0")').css("background-image", "url("+imageUrl+")");
    });
    /* uncomment this event and comment the above event to see the loaded image
    $('span.cleanup').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr td').css("background-image", "url("+imageUrl+")");
    });
    */
    $('span.cleanup').hover(function() {
        $('table tr td p span:contains("0")').css("background-color", "red");
    }, function(){
        $('table tr td p span:contains("0")').css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

You can check out my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6m5jf1/6/), if you comment the first click event and uncomment the second one you see that it load the image. secondly, if I could say you use the right selector by trying changing the `background-color` on `hover` function..

Note: You can use CSS [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property, to shrink the image if you want..

Answer (score 0):

your jquery would be

```
$('document').ready(function() {   
$('span.cleanup').on('click', function() {   
        $('table.masteries').find('span:contains("0")').css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/8b6m5jf1/3/)